# openzeppelin access roles.sol

Tags: solidity, openzeppelin

I'm running this contract on remix https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/access/roles/WhitelistAdminRole.sol

There was no error but i saw an warning "Gas requirement of function addWhitelistAdmin(address) high: infinite.If the gas requirement of a function is higher than the block gas limit, it cannot be executed. Please avoid loops in your functions or actions that modify large areas of storage (this includes clearing or copying arrays in storage)".

What can i do to turn the warning off ?
Should i be worry or just let be ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the message is that you are attempting to call `addWhitelistAdmin` from an account that isn’t a Whitelist admin and the transaction would revert.

For more details see the answer in the OpenZeppelin Community Forum: https://forum.openzeppelin.com/t/question-about-roles-sol/1418

Note: First answered in the Community Forum.

*Disclosure: I am the Community Manager at OpenZeppelin*